# Remove all users from all folders within a Document Library - PowerShell

Tags: powershell, permissions

How to run through all folders in a specific document library to remove inheritance and then remove all users from all folders within a specific Document Library using a Powershell script?

Answer (score 2):

Below are couple of links i mentioned, 1st one using powershell to remove the user and groups from DL and 2nd one is using the code( you can try to create equal powershell for it)

For Powershell, [read this](http://sharepointthinking.wordpress.com/2012/10/01/how-to-remove-users-and-groups-from-a-sharepoint-list-using-powershell/).

For code check this:

**Breaking permission inheritance**

This code will give you how to break inheitance and remove user.

```
SPFolder folder = _MyWeb.GetFolder(documentLibrary + txtFolder.Text);
             SPGroupCollection spc = _MyWeb.SiteGroups;
             SPUserCollection _spUSer = _MyWeb.AllUsers;
      folder.Item.BreakRoleInheritance(true);//Break the inheritance of the created folder in the Document Library
```

The following code will remove all users from the folder. It won't remove the current user who is doing this task.

```
 foreach (SPUser oUser in _spUSer)
                  {
  SPPrincipal principal = (SPPrincipal)oUser;
  SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = new SPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)oUser);
        _MySite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
      _MyWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
         try
                     {
   string ostrCurrentUserName = oUser.LoginName.ToString().Substrin
(oUser.LoginName.ToString().IndexOf('\\') + 1);
                                    if(!ostrCurrentUserName.Equals(strCurrentUserName))

                                        folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Remove((SPPrincipal)oUser);
                                }
                                catch (Exception exx)
                                {
           lblMessage.Visible = true;

                                    lblMessage.Text = oUser + "Doesnt have permission to create
folder";
                                }


                            }
                            //Removing the  sharepoint groups from the folder
                            foreach (SPGroup oGroup in spc)
                            {
                                // Response.Write(SPEncode.HtmlEncode(oGroup.Name) + "<BR>");
                                SPRoleAssignment roleAssignment = newSPRoleAssignment((SPPrincipal)oGroup);

                                _MySite.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                _MyWeb.AllowUnsafeUpdates = true;
                                folder.Item.RoleAssignments.Remove((SPPrincipal)oGroup);

                            }
```

Ref:- [How To make SharePoint document library folder unique Permission Programmatically](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/Roji.Joy/how-to-make-sharepoint-document-library-folder-unique-permission-programmatically/)